# How to use javascript to get the value of checked checkbox dynamically

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I'm new to JavaScript.

I have a webpage that the users can search the document ID and add it to their favourite. after submitting the search criteria, it shows a list ID and a checkbox next to it. so the user can check the checkbox or uncheck it to add and remove them from their list.

My issue is my code can't get the value of the checkbox generated. for example, there are three checkbox generated, chk1,chk2,chk3. when none of them are checked, my code is working I can get the value of the checkbox. but when one of them is checked for example, chk3 is checked, when I check chk1, it still shows the value of chk3 rather than chk1. I want to get the value of that checkbox just checked. I'm struggled to make it right.

```
  <tr><%do until results_rs.EOF%>
   <td class="tdid"><%Response.Write results_rs("id")%></td> 
   <td><input type="checkbox" id="myCheckbox" name ="myf[]" value="<%=results_rs("id")%>" onchange="myfc()">
   <script>

     function myfc(){
     var selchb = getSelectedChbox(this.form);
     alert(selchb)
     }


     function getSelectedChbox(frm) {
         var selchbox = null;
           var chk_arr=document.getElementsByName("myf[]")
           var chklength=chk_arr.length

           for (k = 0; k < chklength; k++) {
               if (chk_arr[k].checked == true)
                 selchbox=chk_arr[k].value
               }
             return selchbox

       **strong text**// rs.close;
       // connection.close
       } 

</script></td>
    <%results_rs.MoveNext%>
    </tr>
```

Comment: IDs need to be unique. Use a class instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minimal change would be to pass `this` into `myfc`:

```
onchange="myfc(this)"
```

...and then use that in `myfc`:

```
 function myfc(cb){
    alert(cb.value);
 }
```

But you might look into more modern event handling with [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) and such.

---

Note that there's no need to put an `id` on the checkbox, and in fact, it's invalid to have more than one checkbox with the same `id`, so probably best to just remove the `id="myCheckbox"` part entirely.

Comment: OMG, it took me whole day and still couldn't get it right. you just few seconds. it works perfectly. thanks for so much.

Answer (score 0):

IDs in JS must be unique. Use a class `class="myCheckbox"`

Then you can do

```
window.addEventListener("load",function() {
  var checks = document.querySelectorAll(".myCheckbox");
  for (var i=0;i<checks.length;i++) { // all .myCheckbox
    checks[i].addEventListener("click",function() {
      console.log(this.checked,this.value); // this specific box
      var checks = document.querySelectorAll(".myCheckbox:checked");
      for (var i=0;i<checks.length;i++) { // all CHECKED .myCheckbox
        console.log(checks[i].value); // only checked checkboxes are shown
      }
    });
  }
});
```

In your case for example

```
window.addEventListener("load",function() {
  var checks = document.querySelectorAll(".myCheckbox");
  for (var i=0;i<checks.length;i++) { // all .myCheckbox
    checks[i].addEventListener("click",function() {
      if (this.checked) myfc(this.value); // this specific box
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help as well.

Comment: I strongly recommend using my suggestion instead of using inline event handlers - change my `console.log(this.checked,this.value);` to `myfc(this.value);`